# How to close text file in Notepad using Java program

Tags: java

I create one text file which contains some data, I want to close that specified text file only. I searched in Google and found the solution as

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM notepad.exe");
```

but it closes all notepad instances, but I want to close specified text file only. This code is for opening sample1.txt file:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String file = "D:\\sample1.txt";
Process p = rt.exec("notepad " +file);
```

This code is for closing the txt file:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM notepad.exe");
```

But here if I opened another text file (not `sample1.txt`) then all text files are closing. My concern is only close the `sample1.txt` file only.

my full code:

```
import java.io.IOException; 

    public class fileCloseOp2 {    
           public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
  InterruptedException {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
              String file = "D:\\sample1.txt";
              Process p = rt.exec("notepad " +file);
              Thread.sleep(5000);                  
              Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM notepad.exe");                 

       }    
}
```

Comment: You can call the `destroy()` method on your `Process` object (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy--). It will kill only the process run by `rt.exec()`.

Comment: Thank you Dorian.it's working.

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
Process p = rt.exec("notepad " +file);
```

That Process object that you *discard* after establishing it ... gives you full **control** over the associated process. For example it offers a method [destroy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy--).

Thus, the *real* answer here: don't use use some API/library calls you found somewhere on the internet. Instead: read the corresponding javadoc, and **understand** why to use some construct, and more importantly: understand what it has to **offer** to you.

In other words: you created an OS process that opened notepad. You can simply use the *handle* that points to that OS process to kill exactly that process!

Comment: hi, how to find the corresponding java doc for this?Please tell me through steps.

Comment: @DeviGeorge 1. Turn to google. 2. Type "java process" + enter. Right the first link that gets shown to me: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html ... or the other way round: know the link to javadoc entry point (like https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/index.html for java 12) ... and navigate through the packages. This is a basic skill, and training it is essential.

Comment: @DeviGeorge And for the record: please dont forget about accepting an answer at some point ;-)